# Printing a 2D array

Tags: java, array, homework

The problem presented to me:

> Declare a two-dimensional array of ints in main. Write a method to read in the size of each dimension, allocate memory for the array and return it (DON'T DO THIS IN MAIN, BUT CALL THIS METHOD IN MAIN).
>   Write another method to initialize each element to the sum of its indices (for example, the element at 3, 4 would have the value 7) (DON'T DO THIS IN MAIN, BUT CALL THIS METHOD IN MAIN).
>   IF TIME, write a method to print the 2-dim. array (use enhanced for loop if you want). (DON'T DO THIS IN MAIN, BUT CALL THIS METHOD IN MAIN)

The output generated by my code:

This is the output which I think is what the above question was asking:

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

I finished this program to print a 2D array. I got the right output, but I'm not sure if I did what was being asked in the problem below.

Can someone please look at the question below and tell me if I miss any part of the question? The part where I got confused was when it said to read in the size of each dimension:

```
package twoDarray;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDarray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array= getArray();
    init_array(array);
    printArray(array);
  }

  public static int[][] getArray() {
    int[][] array = new  int[5][6];
    return array;
  }

  public static int[][] init_array(int[][] array) {

    for(int i = 0; i< array.length;i++)
      for(int j =0; j< array[i].length;j++)
        array[i][j]= i+j;

    return array;
  }

  public static void printArray(int[][] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i< array.length;i++)
      for(int j =0; j< array[i].length;j++)
        System.out.printf("%d\n",array[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that this is the expected format for printing the array?

Comment: Why are you returning the array, when you're obviously using the original reference to the (modified) array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding enhancement

```
public static int[][] getArray(){
  return  new  int[5][6]; // no need of intermediate object
}
```

Optimizing speed : never have a computation or an evaluation at each loop, car be very heavy with great number

```
 for(int i = 0, n = array.lenght;  i < n ; i++) { ..
```

as `init_array` return `array` you can write directly :

```
printArray(init_array(getArray()));
```

Use :

- `System.getProperty("line.separator");` for all OS
- `StringBuilder` then print out :

.

```
public static void printArray(int[][] array){
           String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // You can put it 'public static' elsewhere
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // you can give the size of it between ()
           for(int i = 0; i< array.length;i++)
              for(int j =0; j< array[i].length;j++)
                  sb.append(array[i][j])
                  sb.append(NEWLINE);
              }
           }
           System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read input (from the command line) using the Scanner class for the dimensions of the array.  In this line, you chose 5 and 6:

```
int[][] array = new  int[5][6];
```

Everything looks good except for that method (`getArray`).  In that method, you should read in two numbers from the command line, and use those numbers (instead of 5 and 6) as the dimensions of the array.

Answer (score 1):

### Naming

Consistent: `init_array` might look better if it becomes `initArray`

Accurate: perhaps `processArray` could be used instead of `initArray`, since init means some kind of a **setup**, while the method actually **changes** the array's values.

In addition, perhaps the class' name could be changed from `TwoDarray` to `TwoDimArray`, which, at least in the aesthetic aspect (to my own eyes), looks better.